# The right way to draw a Map when data is ready

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, mapbox

I need to render a map using `Mapbox` only when data is ready.

I have the following code in my Vuex store:

`/store/index.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import _ from "lodash";

import { backendCaller } from "src/core/speakers/backend";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // Activity
    activity: [],
    geoIps: [],
  },

  mutations: {
    // Activity
    setActivity: (state, value) => {
      state.activity = value;
    },
    setGeoIp: (state, value) => {
      state.geoIps.push(value);
    },
  },

  actions: {
    // Activity
    async FETCH_ACTIVITY({ commit, state }, force = false) {
      if (!state.activity.length || force) {
        await backendCaller.get("activity").then((response) => {
          commit("setActivity", response.data.data);
        });
      }
    },
    async FETCH_GEO_IPS({ commit, getters }) {
      const geoIpsPromises = getters.activityIps.map(async (activityIp) => {
        return await Vue.prototype.$axios
          .get(
            `http://api.ipstack.com/${activityIp}?access_key=${process.env.IP_STACK_API_KEY}`
          )
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
          });
      });

      geoIpsPromises.map((geoIp) => {
        return geoIp.then((result) => {
          commit("setGeoIp", result);
        });
      });
    },
  },

  getters: {
    activityIps: (state) => {
      return _.uniq(state.activity.map((activityRow) => activityRow.ip));
    },
  },

  strict: process.env.DEV,
});
```

In my `App.vue` I fetch all APIs requests using an async created method.

`App.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",

  async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_ACTIVITY");
    await this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_GEO_IPS");
  },
};
</script>
```

In my `Dashboard` component I have a conditional rendering to draw the maps component only when `geoIps.length > 0`

`Dashboard.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div v-if="geoIps.length > 0">
    <maps-geo-ips-card />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mapsGeoIpsCard from "components/cards/mapsGeoIpsCard";

export default {
  name: "dashboard",

  components: {
    mapsGeoIpsCard,
  },

  computed: {
    activity() {
      return this.$store.state.activity;
    },
    activityIps() {
      return this.$store.getters.activityIps;
    },
    geoIps() {
      return this.$store.state.geoIps;
    },
};
</script>
```

Then I load the Maps component.

```js
<template>
  <q-card class="bg-primary APP__card APP__card-highlight">
    <q-card-section class="no-padding no-margin">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>

<script>
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl";

export default {
  name: "maps-geo-ips-card",

  computed: {
    geoIps() {
      return this.$store.state.geoIps;
    },
  },

  created() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.MAPBOX_API_KEY;
  },

  mounted() {
    const mapbox = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map",
      center: [0, 15],
      zoom: 1,
    });

    this.geoIps.map((geoIp) =>
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat([geoIp.longitude, geoIp.latitude])
        .addTo(mapbox)
    );
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that when the function resolves the first IP address, the map is drawn showing only one address and not all the others like this:

[image: Mapbox VueJS]

What is the best way to only draw the map when my `FETCH_GEO_IPS` function has finished?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer lies in this bit of code:

```
      geoIpsPromises.map((geoIp) => {
        return geoIp.then((result) => {
          commit("setGeoIp", result);
        });
      });
```

Your `map` function loops through every element of the array and commits each IP one by one. So when the first one is committed, your `v-if="geoIps.length > 0"` is `true`.

A workaround would be to set a flag only when the IPs are set.
This is a proposed solution:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import _ from "lodash";

import { backendCaller } from "src/core/speakers/backend";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // Activity
    activity: [],
    geoIps: [],
    isReady: false
  },

  mutations: {
    // Activity
    setActivity: (state, value) => {
      state.activity = value;
    },
    setGeoIp: (state, value) => {
      state.geoIps.push(value);
    },
    setIsReady: (state, value) => {
        state.isReady = value;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    // Activity
    async FETCH_ACTIVITY({ commit, state }, force = false) {
      if (!state.activity.length || force) {
        await backendCaller.get("activity").then((response) => {
          commit("setActivity", response.data.data);
        });
      }
    },
    async FETCH_GEO_IPS({ commit, getters }) {
        let tofetch = getters.activityIps.length; // get the number of fetch to do
      const geoIpsPromises = getters.activityIps.map(async (activityIp) => {
        return await Vue.prototype.$axios
          .get(
            `http://api.ipstack.com/${activityIp}?access_key=${process.env.IP_STACK_API_KEY}`
          )
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
          });
      });

      geoIpsPromises.map((geoIp) => {
        return geoIp.then((result) => {
          commit("setGeoIp", result);
          toFetch -= 1; // decrement after each commit
          if (toFetch === 0) {
            commit("setIsReady", true); // all commits are done
          }
        });
      });
    },
  },

  getters: {
    activityIps: (state) => {
      return _.uniq(state.activity.map((activityRow) => activityRow.ip));
    },
  },

  strict: process.env.DEV,
});
```

And in your view:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isReady">
    <maps-geo-ips-card />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mapsGeoIpsCard from "components/cards/mapsGeoIpsCard";

export default {
  name: "dashboard",

  components: {
    mapsGeoIpsCard,
  },

  computed: {
    activity() {
      return this.$store.state.activity;
    },
    activityIps() {
      return this.$store.getters.activityIps;
    },
    isReady() {
      return this.$store.state.isReady;
    },
};
</script>
```